# Install pyCurl in ActivePython-2.6?

Tags: python, libcurl, pycurl, activepython

I have worked with pyCurl in the past and have it working with my system default python install. However, I have a project that requires python to be more portable and I am using ActivePython-2.6.

I have had no problems installing any other modules so far, but am getting errors installing pyCurl. 
The error:

```
Searching for pycurl
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pycurl/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/
Reading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/
Best match: pycurl 7.19.0
Downloading http://pycurl.sourceforge.net/download/pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Processing pycurl-7.19.0.tar.gz
Running pycurl-7.19.0/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-tfVLW6/pycurl-7.19.0/egg-dist-tmp-p1WjAy
sh: curl-config: not found
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/bin/easy_install", line 8, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==0.6c9', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1671, in main
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1659, in with_ei_usage
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 1675, in <lambda>
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/core.py", line 152, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 975, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/dist.py", line 995, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 211, in run
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 446, in easy_install
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 476, in install_item
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 655, in install_eggs
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 930, in build_and_install
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 919, in run_setup
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 27, in run_setup
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 63, in run
  File "/opt/ActivePython-2.6/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 29, in <lambda>
  File "setup.py", line 90, in <module>
Exception: `curl-config' not found -- please install the libcurl development files
```

My system does have libcurl installed, but ActivePython doesn't seem to find it.

Any ideas will help!

Answer (score 5):

Following dependencies are needed for installing pycurl:

```
apt-cache depends python-pycurl
python-pycurl
 Depends: libc6
Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
Depends: libgcrypt11
Depends: python2.7
Depends: python
Depends: python
Suggests: libcurl4-gnutls-dev
Suggests: python-pycurl-dbg
Conflicts: <python2.3-pycurl>
Conflicts: <python2.3-pycurl:i386>
Conflicts: <python2.4-pycurl>
Conflicts: <python2.4-pycurl:i386>
Replaces: <python2.3-pycurl>
Replaces: <python2.3-pycurl:i386>
Replaces: <python2.4-pycurl>
Replaces: <python2.4-pycurl:i386>
Conflicts: python-pycurl:i386
```

Run this command

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev librtmp-dev
```

Then you can install pycurl using

```
pip install pycurl
```

or

```
easy_install pycurl
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a curl-config to add to the path, which makes sense as it's not a module that can be called (as far as I can tell)

The answer ended up being a bit of a hack, but it works.

As I had pyCurl working in my native python2.6 install, I simply copied the curl and pycurl items from the native install into the ActivePython install.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ apt-cache depends python-pycurl
python-pycurl
  Depends: libc6
  Depends: libcurl3-gnutls
  Depends: libgnutls26
  Depends: libidn11
  Depends: libkrb53
  Depends: libldap-2.4-2
  Depends: zlib1g
  Depends: python
  Depends: python
  Depends: python-central
[...]
```

So first install the dependencies via `sudo aptitude install libcurl3-gnutls` (or the package manager of your distribution) and then run `easy_install pycurl`.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libcurl4-gnutls-dev python-pycurl-dbg librtmp-dev` is what did it for me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `curl-config` isn't in your path. Try running it from the command line and adjust the `PATH` environment variable as needed so that Python can find it.